# Urban Airship Not Requesting Access For Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

After following the extensive start-up guide on Urban Airship's website, I finished.  Upon completion I ran the app on my phone and it ran normally, the console filled up with Urban Airship stuff and everything was going accord to plan but then I noticed that the request to use push notifications never came up.
Currently I'm running the following code in **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.24 blue:0.75 alpha:1]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Color"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    //shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
    //shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
    [UAirship takeOff:config];

    [UAPush shared].notificationTypes = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability);

    [UAPush setDefaultPushEnabledValue:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Yes, I have imported **UAirship.h** etc. correctly, so please don't suggest that.

**CONSOLE:**
I know the production keys aren't valid, but that's because you need a credit card to register them, and I'm waiting on a guardians credit card to come through.

```
2014-06-26 02:13:13.504 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 160] Production App Key is not valid.
2014-06-26 02:13:13.506 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 164] Production App Secret is not valid.
2014-06-26 02:13:13.506 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 147] App Key: (censored)
2014-06-26 02:13:13.506 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 148] App Secret: (censored)
2014-06-26 02:13:13.507 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 149] Server: https://device-api.urbanairship.com
2014-06-26 02:13:13.508 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [D] -[UAirship configureUserAgent] [Line 314] Setting User-Agent for UA requests to Husky Athletics 1.0 (iPhone; iPhone OS 8.0; UALib 4.0.0; (censored); en_US)
2014-06-26 02:13:13.541 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [D] void PrintReachabilityFlags(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, const char *) [Line 79] Reachability Flag Status: WR t----l- networkStatusForFlags
2014-06-26 02:13:13.545 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 193] Registering UAURLProtocol
2014-06-26 02:13:13.555 Husky Athletics[573:83549] Channel ID: (censored)
2014-06-26 02:13:14.269 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [D] -[UAUserAPIClient updateUser:deviceToken:channelID:onSuccess:onFailure:] [Line 117] Updating user (censored).
2014-06-26 02:13:14.274 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [E] -[UAAppDelegate application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] [Line 42] Failed To Register For Remote Notifications With Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x170074e40 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
2014-06-26 02:13:14.589 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [D] __20-[UAUser updateUser]_block_invoke161 [Line 290] Failed to update user
2014-06-26 02:13:28.614 Husky Athletics[573:83821] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 238] Retrieved device id info from keychain.
2014-06-26 02:13:28.615 Husky Athletics[573:83821] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 245] Loaded Device ID: (censored)
2014-06-26 02:13:28.616 Husky Athletics[573:83821] [D] +[UAKeychainUtils getDeviceID] [Line 246] Loaded Model Name: iPhone6,1
2014-06-26 02:13:29.004 Husky Athletics[573:83549] [D] __39-[UAAnalytics sendOperationWithEvents:]_block_invoke [Line 582] Analytics data sent successfully. Status: 200
```

Comment: Something is most likely off in your Apple provisioning then. See here: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#set-up-your-application-with-apple

Comment: I added a production key and created a new provisioning profile and it works flawlessly now!